# Using the same ng-click in different classes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-1.6

So the thing is:

- I have four cards and I have a `ng-click` on the first one with a function named `OpenCard()`.
- When I click, it shows its hidden content.
  I wanna do the same for the rest of the cards, using the same call to `OpenCard()`.
- My four classes have the same name "rowCont" and the hidden content inside that "rowCont" is different:

```
<div class="rowCont" ng-click="OpenCard()" ng-class="{'active': isActive}">      
    <div class="hiddenContent">
        <div class="animate-show" ng-show="cardVisible">

        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

```
$scope.isActive = false;
$scope.OpenCard = function () {
    if($scope.isActive == false) {
      $scope.isActive = true;
      $scope.cardVisible = true;
    } else {
      $scope.isActive = false;
      $scope.cardVisible = false;
    }
  }
```

I'm using Angular 1.6.0
Do you have an idea how can I refer to one card in specific using the same function on `ng-click`? Cause when I click one in one closed card it shows the content of all cards.

Comment: Are you displaying cards with `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Do you have an id for each card? Or something that makes them unique?

Answer (score -1):

You can store card's visibility in an array (`$scope.cardsVisible = [];`), and pass an index in each call to `OpenCard(cardIndex)`.

Then, display it conditionnaly in your view:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.cardsVisible = [];

  $scope.OpenCard = function(cardIndex) {
      $scope.cardsVisible[cardIndex] = true;
      $scope.isActive = cardIndex;
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-click="OpenCard(1)" ng-class="{'active': isActive == 1}">
    Card 1
    <div ng-show="cardsVisible[1]">
      This card is visible
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-click="OpenCard(2)" ng-class="{'active': isActive == 2}">
    Card 2
    <div ng-show="cardsVisible[2]">
      This card is visible
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @downvoter May I know the reason you downvoted, so I can improve my answer? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
       <div class="row"> 
               ng-repeat="x in current_tab 
               ng-class="{active1 : activeMenu === x}"
               ng-click="setActive(x);"> {{x.userId}}
       </div>

$scope.menuItems = $rootScope.current_tab;
$scope.activeMenu = $scope.menuItems[0];
 $scope.setActive = function(menuItem) {
    $scope.activeMenu = menuItem
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var app = angular.module("ngClickApp", []);
app.controller('ngClickCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.cards = [{
    isActive: false,
    title: '1',
    content: 'content 1'
  }, {
    isActive: false,
    title: '2',
    content: 'content 2'
  }];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="ngClickApp">
<head>
 <title>Validation messages</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ngClickCtrl">
<div class="rowCont" ng-repeat="card in cards track by $index" ng-click="card.isActive=!card.isActive" ng-class="{'active': c.isActive}">
    card {{$index}}
    <div class="hiddenContent">
      <div class="animate-show" ng-show="card.isActive">
        {{card.content}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```